# Getting control height in the WPF datacontext

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl that the data is binded to the datacontext of the window
In that ItemsControl I don't want to see the scrollbar, I want there to be pages which you can go to the next page in order to see more records.
going to the next page is not a problem, the problem is that I need to know how many records can I put in a page without displaying the scrollbar, since this is dependent on the height of the record (in this case a constant) and the height of the ItemsControl (which is a mystery).

The question is how can I get the height of the ItemsControl in the class which is the DataContext (using binding) which is dependent on the height of the window and the height of the other objects around it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try ItemsControl.[ActualHeight.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx)
You could bind your ItemsControl to a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to resolve your problem. So you won't need the information of the height in your DataContext.

Comment: The problem is that in the datacontext I don't have the control (so I don't have access to the ActualHeight property) and using a converter will update the height, I don't want to update the height, I want to use the height of the control